# Magento module controller won't update

Tags: php, magento, module, controller

I did some tweaking on a module a guy used for a website he was working on and now I was requested to change one line of code in the controller of that module. The problem: it doens't matter what I do, my changes won't get loaded and Magento uses the old controller code. How do I fix this?

What I tried:

- cache management (refreshed it, flushed it, cleared it and disabled it. I have done all of it in any possible order)
- checked if I was in the right place to begin with (edited etc/config.xml and Block/view.php these changes did show)
- edited etc/config.xml and changed the version number
- System=>Configuration=>Advanced=>Advanced and disabled/enabled the module to check if it would reload it

just to clearify the cache management part:

- Configuration
- Layouts
- Blocks HTML output
- Translations
- Collections Data
- EAV types and attributes
- Web Services Configuration
- Web Services Configuration

are the only rows I have here.

installed Magento version:
Magento ver. 1.8.1.0

If there is anything else you may need to solve this problem please let me know!
I have allready wasted a day on this problem.

Comment: I fixed my problem with a workaround, it seemed that I was able to edit the model. The code that I wrote however didn't work all of the time (long story). I still find it odd that I can't edit the controller though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem with a workaround, it seemed that I was able to edit the model.
The code in the controller was never called because he put the logic that actually was called in the Model.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe compilation mode is enabled.

Go to `System -> Tools -> Compilation` and if compilation is enabled, click `Run Compilation Proces`.

Comment: Thank you for your input, compilation was disabled and just for the sake of trying every possible thing I compiled it. It didn't work though and I disabled it again.